# How to learn OFFICE 365 add-ins (Office.js)

Tags: office365, office-js, office-addins

What is the best book or course to learn how to develop OFFICE 365 add-ins?

Comment: for learning by example, you can try the Script Lab Add-in https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/garage/profiles/script-lab/

Comment: Just to tag along: I found this very helpful: https://hongbo-miao.gitbooks.io/excel/content/

Answer (score 2):

The only book that I know of is: http://buildingofficeaddins.com/book/
There's also the official documentation: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/overview/office-add-ins